# Dirac delta function, sinx

Tags: dirac-delta

How to solve integration of del(sin x)dx
The limits are from minus infinity to plus infinity. Please explain.

Comment: Are you wanting to solve $\int \delta(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$ or $\int \delta(x)\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Use mathjax. What is your definition of $\delta(\sin(x))$. It is obvious $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\sin(x))dx$ isn't well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$
δ(g(x))=\sum_{a:g(a)=0}\frac{\delta(x-a)}{|g'(a)|}
$$
you would get
$$
δ(\sin(x))=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} δ(x-k\pi).
$$

Comment: Starting from $\int δ(cx)f(x)dx=\int δ(u)f(u/c) du/|c|$, apply the linear Taylor expansion around the roots of $g$, you get a sum over all the roots of $g$ in the support of $f$.